# Memory-based files in UNIX

Tags: unix, memory-management, file-io, posix

I have a 3rd party library that can only work on files, i.e referenced using a file name URL like "file:///path/path/file.ext".  But I have some data I want to read from in memory already.

Is it possible to make a in-memory buffer look like a file, that is have a filename, so I can leave out the write memory-buffer to disk step so that the 3rd party library can process it?

Thanks

EDIT:  I've added some code demonstrating what I would like to do:

```
const char* gFileName = "/Users/matthew.davies/Hello";

void MakeMemoryFile (const char* filename, const char* buffer, size_t size)
{

}

void DeleteMemoryFile (const char* filename)
{

}

int main()
{
    const char* buffer = "Hello World!";
    FILE* f;
    char outBuffer [13];


    MakeMemoryFile(gFileName, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    f = fopen(gFileName, "rb");
    outBuffer[12] = 0;
    fread(outBuffer, 12, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    DeleteMemoryFile(gFileName);

    return 0;
}
```

MakeMemoryFile() would create the file so that it can referred to by name later with the fopen.

Comment: You can create a character device that gets its data from a script. I know you can make something like the in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

How about using memory mapped file using mmap() system call if it is unix like OS.

Comment: Because it needs to be referable by filename.

Comment: You can specify file descriptor related to file as mmap() parameter, and use the pointer got from mmap as "buffer".

Comment: But can I "open" that buffer using fopen()?  The 3rd party library requires a filename.  I must only be able access my memory buffer via a filename.

Comment: You can create file, call mmap() with the file descriptor of created file to get buffer, write to buffer, and open(fopen etc) the file created.

Comment: Won't this still access the file system?  I am trying to avoid accessing the file system since its very slow.  I don't see how mmap will help me since I have to create a file on the file system first before I can use it.  I have the buffer, I just need to access it via a filename (and file functions) without using the local file system (e.g. disk).

Comment: If you want to call fopen() without filename, it is probably impossible. And, actually file is not always store physical disk but store memory(as cache), if it is not MSDOS or something...

Comment: I want to use fopen with a filename but then I get back a FILE* that actually accesses my memory buffer and not a file on the file system.  Think of it as a ramdisk :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is making a `tmpfs` (in-memory temporary file system) and writing data there to a `mmap()`ed buffer, though the first step requires root privileges and this scenario is a bit over-complicated.

Another possible approach is rolling a tiny custom FUSE filesystem that exposes some program's memory areas as files (you need to integrate this FS into the program and to add FUSE to your program's dependencies).

Also, Linux does aggressive disk caching, so for not a very huge file it may be good to just leave it to the kernel. For example, Vim handles large tags files (~100Mb) pretty well without explicit caching.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for the iOS operating system to get round the problem that AVFoundation requires a filename, yet I have the data already in memory.